# data member is inaccessible even though the class has been declared as friend class

Tags: c++

The data member is inaccessible even though the class has been declared as friend class. error: 'total' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Produce
{
    private:
        float total;
    public:
        Produce()
        {
            total=0;
        }
        friend class Bill;
};
class Bill
{
    private:
        float grand_total;
    public:
    Bill()
    {
        grand_total=0;
    }
    Bill operator+=(const Produce &p)
    {
        return Bill(total+p.total);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct: there is no name `total` in the current scope. The code should either refer to `grand_total`, which is a member of the class `Bill`, which in turn defines the `operator+=` that's being written, or it should refer to `p.total` to access the `total` that's a member of the class `Produce`.

Answer (score 0):

Making class `A` a friend of class `B` doesn't mean that you can just randomly name non-static members of `B` from within `A`, without naming an instance of `B` to use.

Which `Produce::total` (out of potentially infinite) do you want your program to use?